# Read Body (Payload) of a GET / DELETE in Java play 2.4

Tags: java, playframework, get

I'm using Play 2.4.x framework and I want get the body of a DELETE request. In Play 2.2 this can be simply done using `request().body().asJson().toString()`

According to the [Plat 2.4 migration](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.1/Migration24#Body-Parsers) document, the above method only works for PUT POST and PATCH requests. Not for GET and DELETE. What is the Java code to read the Body of a DELETE request in Play 2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the migration document, they mention that `BodyParsers.parse.default` has changed its behaviour, but you can still access to the body by specifying an other body parser:

```java
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
public Result myAction() {
    return ok("Got json: " + request().body().asJson());
}
```

Note: When using `BodyParsers.Json.class`, it will automatically verify that the incoming request contains some json and parse it.

Comment: Oops didn't see it was a java question, I updated the code